# preg_replace successful or not

Tags: php

Is there any way to tell if a preg_replace was successful or not?

I tried:

```
<?php

$stringz = "Dan likes to eat pears and his favorite color is green and green!";
$patterns = array("/pears/","/green/", "/red/");

if ($string = preg_replace($patterns, '<b>\\0</b>', $stringz, 1)) {
echo "<textarea rows='30' cols='100'>$string</textarea>";
}else{
    echo "Nope. You didn't have all the required patterns in the array.";
    }

?>
```

and yes, I looked at php docs for this one. Sorry about my stupid questions earlier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the last param of preg_replace: `&$count`, which will contain the number of replacements that were done:

```
$stringz = "Dan likes to eat pears and his favorite color is green and green!";
$patterns = array("/pears/","/green/","/green/");
$new_patterns = array();
foreach ($patterns as $p)
    if (array_key_exists($p, $new_patterns))
      $new_patterns[$p]++;
    else
      $new_patterns[$p] = 1;
$string = $stringz;
$success = TRUE;
foreach ($new_patterns as $p => $limit)
{
  $string = preg_replace($p, '<b>\\0</b>', $string, $limit, $count);
  if (!$count)
  {
    $success = FALSE;
    break;
  }
}
if ($success)
  echo "<textarea rows='30' cols='100'>$string</textarea>";
else
  echo "Nope. You didn't have all the required patterns in the array.";
```

**edited** to fix the issue when there are two of the same in `$patterns`

Comment: That looks nice and all but now i get... `Dan likes to eat <b>pears</b> and his favorite color is <b><b>green</b></b> and green!`

Comment: You might want to look at my answer in one of your previous questions (the one with `$new_patterns`).. maybe combine it with this one

Comment: and apparently, the one-time occurrence doesn't want to work! http://pastebin.com/fkwmpPGY :|

Comment: Yeah cambraca, I accidently did and the Firefox gave me a NOT RESPONDING. :|

Comment: Hmm I ran my code, exactly as it is here, and it returned the textbox with this string: `Dan likes to eat <b>pears</b> and his favorite color is <b>green</b> and <b>green</b>!`. I'm not sure what I should be looking at in that pastebin.com link...

Comment: :D it works. sorta. But I get 
Notice: Undefined index: /pears/ in C:\wamp\www\withone\rep.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: /green/ in C:\wamp\www\withone\rep.php on line 6

Comment: Line 6: ` $new_patterns[$p]++; ` o_O That is weird because didn't you already define it? I'll just put an @ in front of it. Not a big deal.

Comment: Ahh that's because I'm doing `$new_patterns[$p]++;`.. I edited it so the notice dissapears...

Answer (score 6):

```
if (preg_replace($patterns, '<b>$0</b>', $stringz, 1) != $stringz)
   echo 'preg_replace was successful'
```

Comment: Isn't the idea to see if _all_ the patterns existed in the string? (if I'm head-parsing this correctly, it will return TRUE if only one is replaced, right?)

Comment: @cambraca: the question focused on whether preg_replace was successful or not. there's no need to waste cpu cycles by testing an infinite number of replacements. and there's no mention of matching ALL.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

> If matches are found, the new subject
>   will be returned, otherwise subject
>   will be returned unchanged or NULL if
>   an error occurred.

So:

```
$string = preg_replace($patterns, '<b>\\0</b>', $stringz, 1);
if($string != $stringz) {
    // something was replaced
}
```

Comment: How can an array equal a sentence? This didn't work for me. :(

Comment: @Dan - are you sure `preg_replace` is returning an array?